# Google App Engine Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed

Tags: google-app-engine

I have deployed an application to Google App Engine which polls for notifications every 7 seconds. The app runs perfectly on local but it is throwing this error and returning null as response:

> Google App Engine- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed

The error is thrown only for a very few requests and most of the requests succeed.

The code I've been using when poll request comes (I'm using Objectify for querying Datastore):

```
@Override
protected final void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    long uId = getLongParam(request, "uId");
    long timestamp = getLongParam(request, "ts");
    // Load notifications
    List<Notification> notifs = ofy().load().type(Notification.class).filter("uId", uId).list();

    // Update users
    updateUser(timestamp)

    // Send response as json
    setJsonResponse(response, new Gson().toJson(notifs));

    // Clear Objectify session cache
    ofy().clear();
}

private void updateUser(final long uId, final long timestamp) {
    ofy().transact(new Work<User>() {
        @Override
        public User run() {
            User user = ofy().load().type(User.class).id(uId).now();
            user.lastOnlineTime = timestamp;
            ofy().save().entity(user).now();
            return user;
        }
    });
}
```

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1024)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:240)
    at com.google.appengine.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:527)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: what are you doing after polling every 7 second?

Comment: The poll reads from a datastore table as well as writes to another datastore table.

Comment: please include the code

Comment: @jirungaray added the code.
PS: I know its not a good idea to do so many reads and writes in every poll and I'm trying to fix this by using memcache.

Comment: well that code doesnt compile (updateUser method is missing params) but other than that... the problem is transaction related. With such a short span my guess id transactions form a slightly slowed down batch are clashing with the new batch of transactions. why not place all users in a list, edit them and save them all in a single tx using save().entities(..)?

Comment: On a design related note, you can't trust GAE to do a get and update of (potentially) many users, that wont scale and even in short numbers remember that GAE instances are continually being destroyed and created which will probably lead to quite a few of collisions. My suggestion is you queue this updates using the Push Queue service and set it to consume only 1 token at a time.